# How a turbo jet engine produces thrust

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, aerospace-engineering, power-engineering

As i read on some website of nasa, that velocity of the gas flowing from nozzle of the jet is responsible for thrust,
But ky confusion is that, as the velocity increases presure should drop at nozzle, and asnthe velocity at the compressor is low, presure must be high there.
And at the time when the gas flow through nozzle, walls of nozzle must experience presure in direction of that of the gas flowing out of the jet, all the forces produced by presure diffrence and that on nozzle is in opposite firection of the movement of the jet,
**Then how does a jet produce a thrust in opposite direction and how velocity of gas flowing out of the nozzle of the jet affect the thrust produced by it.**

Comment: Many text books cover this and there is much on the web - a good search will help you.

Comment: Start with something like: https://www.amazon.com/Engineering-Thermodynamics-S-I-Units-Transfer-1967-09-03/dp/B01FKTAP4Q/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_2?keywords=mass+transfer+rogers+%26+mayhew&qid=1582875270&sr=8-2-fkmr2

Answer (score 0):

It is not only the velocity of the gas that produces thrust, but the mass of the gas per second that is being jetted from the nozzle. Since energy = mass * velocity², this energy drives the jet forward (action produces and equal and OPPOSITE reaction). Blow up a balloon and let it go; same principle.